# eclipse.ini XXMaxPermSize and -vmargs

Tags: eclipse

From my understanding, in the eclipse.ini file, the `XXMaxPermSize`, which is defined before the vm args, is fed to eclipse directly.

I pass my own vm args by adding them into my eclipse shortcut like so:

```
C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

By including the `XXMaxPermSize` here, will this override the one in eclipse.ini?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `-vmargs` on the Eclipse command line the arguments replace **all** vmargs specified in the eclipse.ini unless `--launcher.appendVmargs` is also specified somewhere, see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Comment: But the XXMaxPermSize is not specified within vmargs in eclipse.ini. It is defined before vmargs. So if in my command shortcut, I include -vmargs XXMaxPermSize, will this have any effect?

Comment: Is this the `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` option you as asking about?